# Аndroid backbutton какой код кнопки

Tags: javascript, android

Существует ли код кнопки `android backbutton` и если да то какой?

Использовать KeyEvent не могу, поскольку нету библиотеки и подключить никак не могу

Answer (score 5):

Для этого не нужно никакой библиотеки. Просто в активити переопределяете метод `onBackPressed`, либо `onKeyDown` с перехватом события где `KeyEvent == KEYCODE_BACK`